# Having trouble with MySQL joins

Tags: mysql, outer-join, join

artists table:

```
  Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

songs table:

```
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title    | varchar(80)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| minutes  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| seconds  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sales    | decimal(5,2) | NO   |     | 0.00    |                |
| genre_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |
```

and my junction table song_artist:

```
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| song_id   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| artist_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL
```

So I have artists without songs in my data and songs without artists in my data. I can get the artists without songs to show up using a left then right outer join but I can't seem to get data the opposite way.
I've been trying to use this code to get the songs without any artists in my table:

```
SELECT songs.title, artists.name
    -> FROM songs
    -> RIGHT JOIN song_artist
    -> ON (songs.id = song_artist.song_id)
    -> RIGHT JOIN artists
    -> ON (artists.id = song_artist.artist_id);
```

But it just won't work. And I need the title of all the songs and artists names to show up in my result.

Something like this is what I need my result to be:

```
 title                 | name                          |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------+
| Under Pressure        | Queen                         |
| Let It Be             | Beatles                       |
| Broadway              | Goo Goo Dolls                 |
| I Hope You Dance      | Lee Ann Womack                |
| Turn Off The Light    | Nelly Furtado                 |
| I'm Like a Bird       | Nelly Furtado                 |
| Canon in D            | Barrymoore Chamber Orchestra  |
| Canon in D            | London Philharmonic Orchestra |
| Star Wars             | London Philharmonic Orchestra |
| Sea Drift             | London Philharmonic Orchestra |
| NULL                  | Pop Evil                      |
| NULL                  | Volbeat                       |
| NULL                  | Godsmack                      |
```

However I need NULLs in my name category and not in my title category

Comment: When you do `SELECT *` you should see `NULL` column values for `LEFT / RIGHT JOIN`.. they you can simply add `WHERE artists.id IS NULL` to filter records where a song does not have a artist..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case you can use a `LEFT JOIN` and a `WHERE` clause to return the unmatched rows.
For the **songs without artist**:

```
SELECT songs.*
FROM songs LEFT JOIN song_artist
ON song_artist.song_id = songs.id
WHERE song_artist.song_id IS NULL
```

**Edit**
If you want **all** the songs, including those that **do** and those that **don't** have an artist, then:

```
SELECT songs.title, artists.name
FROM songs 
LEFT JOIN song_artist ON song_artist.song_id = songs.id
LEFT JOIN artists ON song_artist.artist_id = artists.id
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the songs without any artist, you can use `not exists`:

```
select s.*
from songs s
where not exists (
    select 1
    from song_artist sa
    inner join artist a on a.id = sa.artist_id
    where sa.song_id = s.id
)
```

This covers the following cases:

- there is no entry in `song_artist` for the given song
- there is one (or more) entry in `song_artist` for the given song, but the none of the referrenced `artist_id`(s) can be found in table `artist`